# Exporting data to .mat file in python

Tags: python, matlab, io, scipy

I am working on a script in python where I can pipe `ls` output to the script and open all the files I want to work with in python using `scipy.io`, and then I want to take all the imported data, and assign them into a `.mat` file (again using `scipy.io`). I have had success importing the data and assigning it to a dictionary to export, but when I load my output file in MATLAB none of the data looks at all the same.

The data I am importing all has a lat/lon coordinate attached to it so I will use that data as an example. Data is coming from a netCDF (`.nc`) file:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import scipy.io as sio
    import numpy as np

    # script take absolute path inputs (or absolute paths are desirable)
    # to access an abolute path on a linux systen use the command:
    # ls -d $PWD/* OR if files not in PWD then ls -d /absolute_file_path/*
    # and then pipe the standard output of that to input of this script

    # initialize dictionary (param) and cycle number (i.e. datafile number)
    cycle = []
    param = {}

    # read each file from stdin
    for filename in sys.stdin:
        fh = sio.netcdf.netcdf_file(filename,'r')
        # load in standard variables (coordinates)
        latitude = fh.variables['LATITUDE'][:]
        longitude = fh.variables['LONGITUDE'][:]

        # close file
        fh.close()

        # get file number (cycle number)
        cycle = filename[-7:-4]

        # add latest imported coordinate to dictionary
        latvar = 'lat' + cycle
        lonvar = 'lon' + cycle
        param.update({latvar:latitude})
        param.update({lonvar:longitude})

    # export dictionary to .mat file
    sio.savemat('test.mat',param)
```

When I print the values to check if they are imported correctly I get reasonable values - but when I open my exported values in MATLAB this is an example of my output:

```
    >> lat001

    lat001 =

     -3.5746e-133
```

and other variables have similar large exponent value (sometime very small as in this example sometimes extremely large ~1e100).

I have tried looking for similar problems but all I have come across is that some have had issues assigning large amounts of data to a single .mat file (ex. an array exceeding 2**32-1 bytes).

**EDIT**: Some example outputs (loading file in python, datatypes)

```
    print latitude
        [ 43.091]

    print type(latitude)
        <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

    data = sio.loadmat('test.mat')
    print data['lat001']
        array([[ -3.57459142e-133]])
```

Comment: When I have pass data between programs (python/matlab for instance) I tend to use plain text files or csvs. One advantage is that they will work whatever program you decide to use, instead of the proprietary data formats. Just food for thought

Comment: What is the purpose of loading it into python first? Matlab supports netcfd: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/netcdf.html

Comment: Tell us more about the values as seen in Python.  Not just what they look like, but their 'type' and/or 'dtype'.I think the `netcfd` and variable name code is irrelevant.  What does an `io.loadmat` dictionary look like?

Comment: Just added your requested outputs - as far as I understand the `[:]` on the end of `fh.variables['varName']` packs the values into a numpy array. `io.loadmat` gives me the same values in the file as when I load it in matlab.

Comment: It looks like it is storing an array generated with something like ` np.empty((1,))`

Comment: Thumb up for the brodroll suggestion. Have you checked the encoding of the sources, both in Matlab and Phyton. Have you checked the "regional settings" if any?...

Comment: The fact that `loadmat` reads the same value as MATLAB, indicates that it isn't an encoding issue.  I think the value of `latitude` right before `savemat` needs to be exmined further.

Comment: Ended up changing my method a bit - instead of creating so many different dict fields, I would append each loaded vector of values into a matrix and exported much fewer variables in a smaller dict at the end. Numbers look good in MATLAB and just requires a little more indexing, though fewer variables which is actually nicer. If anyone is interested I will post the reviewed code.